# Distance Travelled by a Bullet through Wooden Blocks

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I had to completely delete my previous question just because some people thought it was a homework question while in reality I was asking not how to solve the question I got on my test, but why it is solved the way it is solved.

So this is my second and a different attempt at asking the question. I hope it doesn't get closed.

The question I got on the test was related to the distance travelled by a bullet through Wooden blocks. It involved two cases: One with initial velocity of the bullet as 100m$s^-1$ and the other with initial velocity of the bullet as 200m$s^-1$.

(You don't need to know the exact question. I'll ask what I really wanted to ask below)

The solution to the question assumed that the deceleration of the bullet through the wooden blocks was the same, **regardless** of the initial velocity of the bullet. I wanted to ask why is that so. Why is the deceleration of the bullet through the wooden blocks independent of the initial velocity of the bullet?

Now it kind of makes sense to say that since in both cases we have the same wooden blocks made up of the same material, the **resistance** offered by the blocks would be the same.

But doesn't it also makes sense to say that since the bullet moves faster through the blocks the second time, they experience a greater resistive force.

Because we know that in case of fluids the drag force experienced by a spherical object moving through the fluid is given by:-

**F<sub>d</sub>= 6π$\eta$rv**
(For slow speeds)

So in case of fluids the drag force experienced by the sphere is proportional to the velocity of the sphere.

But in solids that is not the case apparently.

Can someone explain this.

Also please don't close my question again.

Comment: If you assume that the *wood block can only absorb a finite amount of energy before disintegrating* and letting the bullet pass through unimpeded after, then given a block that can absorb half the energy of a single bullet at 100m/s it will take two to block the bullet. At 200m/s, the bullet has twice the velocity and four times the energy, so will take four times the number of wooden blocks, so eight.

Comment: The problem is poorly worded. It doesn't specifically state that it took the two full widths of the blocks to stop the  bullet, but that's apparently what they meant. Any way, since the new kinetic energy is four times greater the thickness of the boards (the stopping distance) must also be four times greater, or 8 boards.

Comment: That is based on the using average impact force times stopping distance equals the change in kinetic energy

Comment: What I wanted to ask was about the right side of the work energy principle equation. "Fd" or "mad". I wanted to know why does the acceleration (deceleration)remain the same regardless of the initial velocity of the bullet. Read the last portion of my question to know what I am talking about

Comment: It's an assumption that is implicitly made by the person who posed the problem.  It may or may not be correct.  A more interesting question (and one I don't know the answer to) might be "do experiments actually support this assumption?"

Comment: @MichaelSeifert A problem with this would be that the OP's question is about cases in which there is one unchanging bullet which varies only in velocity after penetrating a solid barrier at 2000m/s. It's hard to imagine anyone having a practical interest in such experiments, as no commercially available shell would qualify. Maybe a perfectly spherical hardened steel bullet, launched by a discarding sabot, if it didn't shatter on impact...